# Typescript not omitting types properly

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to make a function which takes either a number or the string 'last' and uses corresponding element from an array.

I handle the case where input is 'last'.

I've added a simplified example. [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=14&pc=2#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVwLYQBuwAKhABSYBccKSeARsFHAD5wDkANgIYDOMDgEo4AbwBQcOFGAwkUXOQAmmPmB4w0ACxoAxVBmwoANHADmsgMowNwGuSEBeAHwComFGYDaAXREuxSSk4NBwBOAFbOEdzKxsYYAcAbiCpTAQ4SmjHGO5+QREJYODMaIj44AA6LmBPGC04AFo4AEYU4oBfVLgVNQ1tciLiuA8lUBpMY26pYAQEYAwHQOHgmTkFctsvTB924a7OoT2OlI6gA)

I'm getting an error on the `return state[i]` line.

I tried moving `dispatch...` to an if block with `(typeof i === 'number')` but that doesn't work either.

```
export function moveTo(i: number | 'last') {
  return (dispatch: Function, getState: ()=>string[]) => {
    const state = getState();
    if (i === 'last') {
      i = state.length - 1;
    }
    dispatch({
      index: i, //here i is shown to be number on hover
      effect() {
        return state[i]; // index expression is not of type number (shows as number | 'last')
      }
    });
  };
}
```

I want to assert after the if statement that `i` is `number` so that I don't have to use `as number` everywhere in the effect function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type for `i` in the `effect` callback is not narrowed, because `i` is considered a mutable parameter of function `moveTo`.

That means, when `effect` callback is invoked sometime later, the compiler cannot be sure that `i` still has a `number` type. As a consequence, the type guard induced by `if (i === 'last') {i = state.length - 1;}` is invalidated, and `i` gets the initial `number | 'last'` type in the callback.

So when does TS consider function parameters as `const`?

Function parameters are [implicitly treated as `const`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10357), until you make an assignment to the parameter somewhere in the function or a nested function. When a parameter is an implicit `const`, its narrowed type is still accessible in nested function expressions and arrow functions via [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#control-flow-based-type-analysis)/type guards. So, this contrived [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=11&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVwLYQBuwAKhABSYBccKSeARsFHAD5wDkANgIYDOMDgEo4AbwBQcOFGAwkUXOQAmmPmB4w0ACxoAxVBmwoANHADmsgMowNwGuREBeAHxwBUTCjMBtALpPXCSkpTAQ4SjgAQkdHTl4BYUlgqRU1DW1yIOTgzyVQGkxjJOy4YAQEYAwHMWKS6Vl5XAsYa1sHb0xfAG5a5IBfXrg+oSS+nr6gA) works:

```
export function moveTo(i: number | 'last') {
  return (dispatch: Function, getState: () => string[]) => {
    if (i !== 'last')
      dispatch({
        index: i,
        effect() {
          return getState()[i];
        }
      })
  };
}
```

And what to do now?

Your best bet probably is to [declare a new `const` variable](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10180) (see also @D. Nathanael's answer), which produces more consistent types than `as number` casts in the callback.  [Airbnb JavaScript Style Guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#functions--reassign-params) does not recommend function parameter re-assignments, so you could see that as chance to [clean up](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-param-reassign) the code a bit by treating `i` as immutable.

Answer (score 2):

Since `i` can be a `string` and a `number` the linter struggle to understand the conversion. One solution is to use another variable:

```
export function moveTo(i: number | 'last') {
  return (dispatch: Function, getState: ()=>string[]) => {
    const state = getState();
    const index: number = (i == 'last') ? state.length - 1 : i;

    dispatch({
      index,
      effect() {
        return state[index];
      }
    });
  };
}
```

Also, it's a bad thing to have multiple types for the same variable (as things like that can occur), I suggest using `-1` instead of `'last'` to keep with the `number` type.

Comment: but it's able to infer in `index: i` line that i is number

Comment: The `index` property in your `dispatch` is not typed, it's a free object.

Comment: same thing happens when dispatch is typed [see](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=14&ssc=2&pln=9&pc=7#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVwLYQBuwAKhABSYBccKSeARsFHAD5wDkANgIYDOMDgEo4AbwBQcOFGAwkUXOQAmmPmB4w0ACxrkeVUZhRLQNOo2YAaOMAQJgGXUIC8APgFQjAcwC+L14QQmErWXrIAyjAawE5uHt4A2gC6Im5iklJwaDgCcALRcM5wYTCR0eRCANwZUpgIcJSFzkXc-IIiEpmZmIV5UTDAAHRcwCheMFpwALRwAIzVXT41cCpqGtrknV1wRiYgNJiWy1K29hgV6duZMnIKfdEJmEkL20uLVRk+1T5AA)

Comment: Wow yeah, seems like putting it in another variable [works as well](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVwLYQBuwAKhABSYBccKSeARsFHAD5wDkANgIYDOMDgEo4AbwBQcOFGAwkUXOQAmmPmB4w0ACxrkeVUZhRLQNOo2YAaOMAQJgGXUIC8APgFQjAcwC+L14QQmErWXrIAyjAawE5uHt4A2gC6Im5iklJwaDgCcALRcM5wYTCR0eRCANwZUpgIcJSFzkXc-IIiEpmZmIV5UTDAAHRcwCheMFpwALRwAIzVXT7iNVk58GjyMijwRfkDCZhJC5kqahra5J1dcEYmIDSYlitStvYYFenXmTJyClmboxgx0WKz8xx81R8QA). Maybe that `i` is calculated when function `effect` is called.

Comment: You could do `state[this.index]` instead of `state[i]`, it seems to fix the issue.